# Атрибуты id для head и class для body, зачем они?

Tags: html

На сайте прописано <body class="common"> вместо обычного <body>, <head id="Head1"> вместо обычного <head>. Вроде эти теги не имеют атрибутов, по крайней мере не встречал ранее. Зачем они нужны и нужны ли вовсе?

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле, здесь есть смысл. Например, для

`<body class="common">`

могут просто прописываться CSS-стили в классе "common". Например, выравнивание, цвет, бэкграунд и т.д
Вообще, каждый элемент DOM-структуры HTML-страницы имеет как минимум атрибут "id".
Это необходимо для того, чтобы было возможно обращение к элементу с определенным id для его последующей модификации JS-функцией

`document.getElementById(id);`

А вот хедер может иметь ID, например, затем, чтобы менять содержимое мета-тегов и прочих параметров раздела HEAD:

```
<head id="Head1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<script>
obj = document.getElementById("head1").firstChild;
obj.setAttribute("content","text/html; charset=windows-1251");
</script>
```

Данный скрипт меняет кодировку с "UTF-8" на "Windows-1251".

Answer (score 2):

body тоже тег, поэтому, присвоив ему id или class, можно управлять его отображением наравне с другими тегами. Пример использования - перещелкивание классов через js и смена скина сайта.

Answer (score 1):

надо смотреть на конкретный случай.
Часто бывает, что таким методом пользуются для кроссбраузерности.
Например, скрипт определяет возможности браузера и добавляет body определённые классы, а уже в css на эти классы прописаны соответствующие стили. Так, например, работает modernizr.

Comment: http://sletat.ru/ - вот сам сайт, по сути он из одних скриптов и состоит, может в этом все и дело тогда?

Comment: В данном конкретном случае автор кода обладает на редкость оригинальным мышлением, одной из характерных особенностей которого является склонность к использованию собственных развёрнутых масштабных решений взамен общепринятых стандартных.
Автор кода подошёл к задаче творчески, как художник, но не ремесленник.
А кто их знает, этих художников, что они имеют в виду. Мы программисты, у нас душевная организация попроще.

Answer (score 0):

Для <head> смысла действительно не вижу, а вот для <body> это нормально. Например:обнулить отступы или наоборот сделать 5px отступ и т.п.

Comment: а ну для body - я думаю, что для яваскрипта какието якоря.

Comment: А у вас что, на странице много тегов `body` и вы для каждого прописываете id?

    body {
      margin: 5px;
    }

Не, не слышали?

Comment: http://sletat.ru/ - вот сам сайт, по сути он из одних скриптов и состоит, может в этом все и дело тогда?

Comment: Я вас удивлю, но можно и так, разницы в эффекте не будет:

> .common {
>  margin: 5px;
> }
> <body class="common">

Comment: хе-хе:
>body.common {background:#fff url(images/bg_html.png) repeat-x left top;min-height:100%;height:100%;min-width:980px;font-family:trebuchet ms, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;color:#646464;position:relative;font-size: 13px;}

Comment: Сам сайт написан на ASP, может IDE в которой делали автоматом пихает и т.п.?
В CSS файлах и JS скриптах упоминание Head1 нету...

Comment: Для body определить класс это нормально, ведь на разных страницах могут быть разные стили body.